# What is the difference between computeScalingRotation and computeRotationScaling

Tags: eigen, matrix-decomposition

In [the documentation of Eigen's Transform class](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Transform.html), there are two member functions with almost identical signatures:

```
void computeRotationScaling(RotationMatrixType*, ScalingMatrixType*) const
void computeScalingRotation(ScalingMatrixType*, RotationMatrixType*) const
```

Both functions have the identical documentation (The multiplication order is `rotation * scaling` in both functions).

> decomposes the linear part of the transformation as a product rotation x scaling, the scaling being not necessarily positive.
>
> If either pointer is zero, the corresponding computation is skipped.
>
> This is defined in the SVD module.

What is the difference between them?

Comment: This is a typo in the doc, the online doc will automatically update soon. The second is of course `scaling x rotation`.

Answer (score 0):

There difference is in the order. If you look closely, the difference is:

```
// computeRotationScaling
if(scaling) scaling->lazyAssign(svd.matrixV() * sv.asDiagonal() * svd.matrixV().adjoint());
// computeScalingRotation
if(scaling) scaling->lazyAssign(svd.matrixU() * sv.asDiagonal() * svd.matrixU().adjoint());
//                                        ^                                 ^
```